# ASyncTask on MainActivity block UI Layout

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, android-activity, android-asynctask

I got the following code, i don't know why is the main ui blocking (wait DoaJsonReader to complete). Yes, i already read all other question, usually the problem is arround misuse of .get() method. But i don't use it anywhere.

The program is run well but the layout is not loaded, it just showing blank activity with a header as long as DoaJsonReader executed and show a glimpse (around 0.5s) of the layout after the ASyncTask finished.

here my code :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Loading extends Activity {
    private Thread thread;
    DoaData DD;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);
        DD = new DoaData(this);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading app resources ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        DoaJsonReader jr = new DoaJsonReader();
        jr.execute("http://myweb.id/APPS/DOA/?i=index.json");
    }

    private class DoaJsonReader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = "";
            for (String url : urls) {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                    InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += s;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            String lastupdate="";
            try {

                //jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                jsonObject= new JSONObject(result);
                lastupdate=jsonObject.get("lastupdate").toString();

                jsonArray=new JSONArray(jsonObject.get("index").toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            DD.truncateIndex();
            for(int i = 0, count = jsonArray.length(); i< count; i++)
            {
                try {
                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    DD.insertIndex(jsonObject.getString("title").toString(),jsonObject.getString("file").toString(),jsonObject.getString("tags").toString());
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    DD.insertParam("lastupdate",lastupdate);
                }
            }
            finish();
        }
    }

}

public class DoaData extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DOA.db";
    public static final String TABLE_DOA = "DOA_INDEX";
    public static final String TABLE_PARAM = "DOA_PARAM";

    public DoaData(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_DOA);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_PARAM);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_DOA+" (title TEXT,file TEXT, tags TEXT);");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_PARAM+" (key TEXT,value TEXT);");
    }
    public void insertIndex(String title, String file, String tags){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("title",title);
        cv.put("file",file);
        cv.put("tags",tags);
        db.insert(TABLE_DOA,null,cv);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
    public List<DoaIndex> getIndexes() {
        List<DoaIndex> DoaIndexList = new ArrayList<DoaIndex>();
        String selectQuery = "Select * From " + TABLE_DOA +";";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        int i = 0;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                DoaIndex idx = new DoaIndex(i, cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                DoaIndexList.add(idx);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            db.close();
        }
        return DoaIndexList;
    }
    public void truncateIndex(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+TABLE_DOA+";");
        db.execSQL("VACUUM;");
        db.close();
    }
    public void insertParam(String key, String value){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("key",key);
        cv.put("value",value);
        db.insert(TABLE_PARAM, null, cv);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you debug onPostExecute() ?

Comment: Yes i have, it run normally. What do you want to know?

Comment: why you call  finish(); in onPostExecute() ? and what is DoaData ?

Comment: Because i want after the data from web finished loaded it go back to **MainActivity**. I call the **Loading** (Activity) from the **MainActivity**, i already try to change launch activity to **Loading** and call **MainActivity** afterwards but it doesn't change anything (the UI still blocked). 
Doa data is my SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: Can you please try to put your DD related code after JSONArray initialization into runOnUiThread().

Comment: I already update the above code. FYI i already try to comment all DD related command and it doesn't have effect to the locked UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED : I endup recreate all activity & layout using different name and then move all insert to database code to doInBackground method.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

either remove DoaJsonReader jr = new DoaJsonReader(); or do directly

jr.execute("http://myweb.id/APPS/DOA/?i=index.json");

Comment: Sorry i have edited the code.
I have either using :

`DoaJsonReader jr = new DoaJsonReader();
jr.execute("http://myweb.id/APPS/DOA/?i=index.json");`
or

`new DoaJsonReader().execute("http://myweb.id/APPS/DOA/?i=index.json");`


it doesn't have effect

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
class DoaJsonReader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                }

                JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                String lastupdate="";
                jsonObject= new JSONObject(response);
                lastupdate=jsonObject.get("lastupdate").toString();
                jsonArray=new JSONArray(jsonObject.get("index").toString());
                DD.truncateIndex();
                for(int i = 0, count = jsonArray.length(); i< count; i++)
                {
                    try {
                        jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        DD.insertIndex(jsonObject.getString("title").toString(),jsonObject.getString("file").toString(),jsonObject.getString("tags").toString());
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally {
                        DD.insertParam("lastupdate",lastupdate);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have try it, it give me the following error
`Error:(85, 44) error: local variable jsonArray is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final...`
I have move all variable to mainclass and eliminate all error, but it doesn't solve the problem.
Can i know why do we run another Thread inside an ASyncTask?
thanks btw

Comment: Okay then move JSONArray jsonArray variable at class member level like above onCreate().

Comment: Ok, i already moved all variable to main class
`public class Loading extends Activity {
    private Thread thread;
    DoaData DD;
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    String lastupdate="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...`

it doesn't have effect to the program.